# how to exchange data between two Blackberry Applications?

Tags: java, blackberry

To exchange data between apps I have created 2 applications, one is a UI application and the other is a background application, by setting an [alternate entrypoint](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800901/How_To_-_Setup_an_alternate_entry_point_for_my_application.html?nodeid=800820&vernum=0)
I was able to find a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920839/how-can-i-call-background-application-from-ui-applicationblackberry) but was not able get the help I need there
I am able to create [Global Events and a Global Listener](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/796557/800332/800620/What_are_-_Global_Events_and_Global_Event_Listeners.html?nodeid=800527&vernum=4.),
but my problem is how to transfer Data from one application to another.

In UI APPLICATION we can post globalEvent

```
ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().postGlobalEvent(0xba4b84944bb7);
```

In Background Application we can Listen and send the Acknowledgement

```
public void eventOccurred( long guid, int data0, int data1, Object object0, Object object1)
    {
        //Is this the GlobalEvent we are waiting for?
        //Long = com.samples.globalEventFiring.GlobalEventListening
        if (guid == 0x7d3a74a5ccfe6483L)
        {
            //Yes it is.

            System.out.println("Acknowledgement received.");

            UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    Dialog.alert("Event was fired and acknowledged.");
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

But how to transfer data from background application to ui application.How UI application can access data or objects of background application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [Runtime storage](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/5779/Runtime_store_510466_11.jsp) as a central location to share your data between background and UI thread.

Comment: but is it not possible to exchange between them directly?

Comment: Will this runtime storage require registration for test on simulator also?Pls reply its urgent?

Comment: what registration? if you are asking about code signing, no code signing is not required for testing on simulator.

Comment: The runtime store lets 2 applications share memory directly.  On the BB, "processes" are really separate threads in the same JVM.  You can share anything you want in the RT store.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the int and Object arguments in the event system to pass data between the application instances.    When posting the event, use the [postGlobalEvent](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/ApplicationManager.html#postGlobalEvent%28long%2C+int%2C+int%2C+java.lang.Object%2C+java.lang.Object%29) overload that takes ints and Objects.  And in the event handler, downcast object0 or object1 as necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,I have 1 more doubt.from UI Application I will post a GlobalEvent,and on this call Background Application will interact with server and will get the requested data,but at UI application,I want to proceed only after receiving of result from background application.How should I make UI Apllication dependent on background application.

Comment: Send an event from the background app to the UI app.    You will have to setup the UI app to wait for the event to be posted - use locks or polling.   But that is a distinct question from cross-app communication.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911450/how-to-get-lock-of-one-application-for-other-in-blackberry                            Please help in my second doubt,it will be great help

Comment: sorry for inconvenience have uploaded here   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918565/how-to-get-lock-of-one-application-for-other-in-blackberry